# Server form-based authentication can't performed by running index.jsp but servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, j-security-check

While run `index.jsp` then it must check by method  `POST` of servlet and task must be go further. But while I'm trying, it doesn't do what it should be.
Executing servlet can perform this task, but if execute  `index.jsp` it shown  `error.jsp` as entered wrong credentials but can't perform action by `POST` method. Page rendering back to  `index.jsp`.
Why it so?

index.jsp

```
  <form method="POST" action="j_security_check">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspasing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Username:&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="j_username">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Password:&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="password" name="j_password">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Login"</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

error.jsp

```
<title>Login Error</title>
</head>
<body>
    There was an error logging in. Please try again.
</body>
```

ControllerServlet.java

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
response.getWriter().println("Welcome");
```

Comment: The server doesn't provide the controller....how do you expect it to guess that it should it trigger a redirect to admin.jsp?

Comment: @unwichtich See I've facing this now. Server does not provide controller but it provides predefined names j_username and j_password to authenticate. So how about problem I'm facing now?